# Robolectric Initialization Error in Eclipse

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm currently following [this tutorial](http://robolectric.org/eclipse-quick-start/) on using Robolectric for Eclipse. And I can't seem to make it work. It keeps throwing `initializationError` and in the Failure Trace it has a `java.lang.noClassDefFoundError`

[image]

The tutorial seems like it's not enough. Or updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I downloaded the wrong Robolectric jar file. You have to use the `jar-with-dependencies.jar` found [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.robolectric%22). Then everything went well.